# Conditional rendering component renders other component for short period and renders the original component

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I am rendering a component based on a condition of looping . Till the condition gets satisfied it renders no result component and when the condition gets satisfied the wanted component renders. But I need only the satisfied component to render without showing the no result page .

```
{!sourceConfigList.includes(source) ? 
                <Result
                    status="404"
                    title="No Source"
                    subTitle="The Source Does Not Exist"
                    extra={<Link to="/"><Button className="no- 
   source-btn" type="primary">Back Home</Button></Link> }
                />
   : 
    <div className="card-main-flex" >
        <Button type="primary" onClick={this.handleSettings}
             className="source-setting-icon" icon="setting">
         Source Configs
        </Button>
         </div>}
```

I want to render only the condition satisfied component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same code, but without ternary operator. You may try this code.

```
{
!sourceConfigList.includes(source) &&
                <Result
                    status="404"
                    title="No Source"
                    subTitle="The Source Does Not Exist"
                    extra={<Link to="/"><Button className="no- 
   source-btn" type="primary">Back Home</Button></Link> }
                />
}
```

Comment: could you  include the other component too

Comment: I don't understand. The code above helps you to render only when the condition satisfies, which is the issue you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a boolean value in state that tells you that the data is fetched from the api or not, and based on that value you render the component.

Below is the basic code example for the same.

```
class MyCustomComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      isSourceLoaded: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
      console.log(result)
          this.setState({
            users: result.data,
            isSourceLoaded: true,
          });
        }
      )
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isSourceLoaded) {
      if(this.state.users.length) {
        return (
          <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state.users)}</div>
        );
      }
      return (<div>Data not available</div>);
    }

    return (<div>Loading data from source ...</div>);
  }
}

React.render(<MyCustomComponent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```